# Mock EntityEntry NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mocking, moq

I'm doing some unit tests for an `EntityEventListener` from NHibernate, and I'm got stuck trying to mock `FlushEvent` or the `EntityEntry`.

As EntityEntry doesn't have a public constructor, and type Mock must be an interface, an abstract or non-sealed class.

```
EntityEntry ee = new EntityEntry(); //NOT
_entityEntryMock = new Mock<EntityEntry>(); //NOT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without some elaboration, I can't say if this makes sense for you specifically, but when I hit a situation like this (a class that I can't mock with Moq and I can't build), I call in the big guns with an isolation framework.  I generally use [Moles](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/), but there are other options like Typemock Isolator, and I think Moles itself is being replaced in the next .NET framework with a built-in isolator called "Fakes".  But suffice it to say, you're attempting to use Moq for something it's not intended to do -- it just creates mocks "naturally" without serving as an isolation framework.